# Non number theory prerequisites for Alan Baker's *A comprehensive course in number theory*

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I was thinking of buying the book mentioned in the title and wanted to find out the non number theory prerequisites for it (I’ve found no information at all regarding that).

If I may request that you be specific as to how much of a certain topic or course I may need. In other words use terms like “elementary definitions in set theory” instead of “set theory” (if that is the case).
My math background is made up mostly by the courses I’ve taken so far in my CS degree: calc 1&2, linear algebra 1&2, probability, statistics, discrete mathematics, mathematical logic and ordinary differential equations.

Comment: It did not take me long to [find this](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15868332-a-comprehensive-course-in-number-theory) which says "Beginning with the rudiments of the subject, the author proceeds to more advanced topics. . ."

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you’ve misunderstood me which is my fault completely because I didn’t specify that I’m talking about non number theory prerequisites. I have edited my question. (Btw I have read that link you sent)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't familiar with this book before seeing your question, but having looked through it, I would say it is aimed, particularly starting in its middle chapters, at readers with a much higher level of sophistication than you describe. In terms of both specific facts and overall mathematical maturity, I would say the book requires one to have had introductions to analysis and abstract algebra roughly at the level of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and Artin's *Algebra*. A knowledge of the residue calculus (part of beginning complex analysis) is necessary for some of the later material.

For someone with your level of preparation, a book like Stark's *An Introduction to Number Theory* might be more appropriate. Other recommendations can be found [here.](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/115/other_books.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Putting mathematical maturity aside. Do you have an idea of how much scrambling and searching on the internet I will need to do to overcome this knowledge gap? Will pulling up a YouTube video once in a while suffice (assuming I will understand the video)? Or will it be necessary to basically learn a whole new course?

Comment: I can't really imagine going from the level of preparation you describe in your question to being able to read this book profitably by looking things up on the internet. One might manage the first few chapters.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’ll challenge myself and probably get it anyway :)